# Picture numbering

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have a picture, that i want to reference, but the ref is messed up:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}


\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

...

\chapter{three}

\section{one}

\section{two}

Lorem ipsum on picture~\ref{fig:lipsum}.

\begin{figure}
  \textbf{\caption{Lorem ipsum}}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{lipsum}
  \label{fig:lipsum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And what I get is:
`Lorem ipsum on picture 3.2.1` while I want to have only `picture 1`

Comment: I don't get this strange reference reported by the O.P.

Comment: Just remove the `\textbf` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the error comes from the location of the `\label`.

Please, put the label **always** directly after the command, that changes a relevant counter, in this case the `\caption`.

In your case, you also have to include it into the `\textbf{...}` command.

Here is my solution:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}


\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

...

\chapter{three}

\section{one}

\section{two}

Lorem ipsum on picture~\ref{fig:lipsum}.

\begin{figure}
  \textbf{\caption{Lorem ipsum}
  \label{fig:lipsum}}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or rather you should remove the `\textbf` there is no possible reason to put a structural command such as `\caption` inside an in-line font change!

Answer (score 2):

You should never try to affect the formatting of structural elements such as headings or captions by surrounding them in  font changes or other local formatting.

In the case of `report` class it sort of half works, but in most classes the caption formatting will use a specified style and not be affected by the current font settings. But even in `report` class it is structurally wrong to use font changes here.

You can most easily specify that captions use a bold setting using the `caption` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

...

\chapter{three}

\section{one}

\section{two}

Lorem ipsum on picture~\ref{fig:lipsum}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{lipsum}
  \label{fig:lipsum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I didn't knew it!